# Why can't Typescript infer the type of an export from a module, using the export's name?

Tags: typescript

I want to lazily load some exports from some modules, and perform some side-effects on any modules loaded in this way.

Consider this module:

```
// myModule.ts

export const message = `hello`;

export const date = new Date();
```

Here's a helper to lazily load a module, perform side-effects, and return a specific export:

```
// lazy.ts

export const lazy = async<ModuleShape>(
    path: string,
    exportName: keyof ModuleShape,
) => {
    const module = await import(path) as ModuleShape;
    // Do some side effects here...
    return module[exportName];
};
```

Here's an example of it in use:

```
// main.ts

import { lazy } from './lazy.ts';

import type * as myModule from './myModule.ts';

const lazyMessage = await lazy<typeof myModule>(`./myModule.ts`, `message`);

console.log(lazyMessage);
```

The issue is that `lazyMessage` has the union type of `"hello" | Date`. Since I specified the `message` export, I expected `lazyMessage` to have the specific type of `"hello"`.

That is: I expect Typescript to be able to infer the type of an import's export in the same way it infers the type of an object's property:

```
export const myModule = { date: new Date(), message: `hello` };

export const lazy = <
    ModuleShape,
    ExportName extends keyof ModuleShape = keyof ModuleShape
>(module: ModuleShape, exportName: ExportName) => {
    return module[exportName];
};

const lazyMessage = lazy(myModule, `message`); // Typescript "knows" this is a string

console.log(lazyMessage);
```

I can get the right specificity by also passing in the export's name as a generic argument...

```
// lazy.ts

export const lazy = async<
    ModuleShape,
    ExportName extends keyof ModuleShape = keyof ModuleShape
>(
    path: string,
    exportName: ExportName,
) => {
    const module = await import(path) as ModuleShape;
    // Do some side effects here, then...
    return module[exportName];
};
```

...but this means writing the export's name twice, which feels redundant:

```
// main.ts

// Have to write `message` twice
const lazyMessage = await lazy<typeof myModule, `message`>(`./myModule.ts`, `message`);
```

Why doesn't Typescript correctly infer the type of the export in the first case?

Comment: You seem confused about the difference between compile time and run time. A dynamic import is just that: **dynamic**: there is no way for the compiler to be able to tell at compile-time the result of a runtime operation (especially one that could be a HTTP call) like that. Note that following the same logic your generic is a lie: you don't do any validation of the schema of the returned module you're only casting it. This is why e.g. the fetch API is **not** generic over the returned Response. I'm no purist if this is only for your own use and you are willing to accept the caveats go for it...

Comment: ...but please don't expose something like this for somebody else to use without spelling out the guarantees or lack thereof around type-safety. An alternative would be to have the caller pass in a (potentially optional) validator or return type `unknown` to force the caller to cast or validate the module themselves.

Comment: Because you are casting it in your function. But the cast (like all casts) is you telling the compiler "I know what the type of this thing is even though you can't prove it": there's no *actual* guarantee from the compiler because you told it "I got this". If you remove the cast and the file is a local file with declarations the compiler can resolve (i.e. you spell out a path to someFile.js and there's a someFile.d.ts in the same directory) it will resolve it for you and you'll get the correct types but if this code is meant to run client side in a browser or all bets are off.

Comment: @JaredSmith Sorry, I deleted that comment right after posting it because I realized the answer was that Typescript "knows" the shape because it's explicitly cast, like you said. To be fair, isn't _all_ of Typescript's type-checking system a "lie"? If the code compiles, it may run just fine even if everything was mis-cast. To put the question another way, why can't Typescript infer the type of an import's export just as it can infer the type of an object's property? I've updated the question with an example along these lines.